# Injection error with controllers and service in same module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a single angular module that has controllers and a service defined in the same module. Im getting and unknown provider error [Error: $injector:unpr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=). I'm not redefining the module multiple times so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
// index.js
var pdizzApp = angular.module('pdizzApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'blogModule'
]);

pdizzApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/blog', {
            templateUrl: 'app/blog/view/blog-list.html',
            controller: 'BlogListController'
        })
        .when('/blog/:postId', {
            templateUrl: 'app/blog/view/blog-detail.html',
            controller: 'BlogDetailController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/blog'
        })
}]);



//blogModule.js
var blogModule = angular.module('blogModule', []);

blogModule.factory('PostService', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/blog/post/:postId', {}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {postId: 'posts'}, isArray: true}
        });
    }]);

blogModule.controller('BlogListController', ['$scope', 'PostService',
    function ($scope, PostService) {
        $scope.posts = PostService.query();

        /**
         * Turn the string into a Date object
         * @param date
         * @returns {Date}
         */
        $scope.toDate = function(date) {
            return new Date(date);
        };
    }]);

blogModule.controller('BlogDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PostService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, PostService) {
        $scope.post = PostService.get({postId: $routeParams.postId});

        /**
         * Turn the string into a Date object
         * @param date
         * @returns {Date}
         */
        $scope.toDate = function(date) {
            return new Date(date);
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=

Comment: Can you post some more code ? _Did you include angular-route.js in your HTML_ ? Which provider do you think is throwing this error ?

Comment: You are using `$resource` but didn't inject the dependency into the module, same goes for `$routeParams`: `angular.module('blodModule', ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]);`

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can find is that `blogModule` needs to use `ngRoute` module, in order to be able to inject `$routeParams`

so change

```
var blogModule = angular.module('blogModule', []);
```

to

```
var blogModule = angular.module('blogModule', ['ngRoute']);
```